# Lua won't execute bash script

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, lua

I'm using Lua script with ngnix to generate ISO file.
Lua script is parsing request and it should pass it to `genisoimage` command.

I've tried with:

```
local pack_cmd = "genisoimage -V" .. some_other_name
os.execute(pack_cmd)
```

Command is not successfully executed and as return code I get `3328`. I've
tried with absoulte path (`/usr/bin/genisoimage` and `/bin/genisoimage`) but
it's not working.

I've tried simple workaround - Execute `genisoimage` command inside bash script
and in Lua script run it like this:

```
local pack_cmd = "bash /absoulte/path/script.sh " .. some_other_name
os.execute(pack_cmd)
```

Still not working and getting same exit code. Also tried to catch what's wrong but it look likes command `genisoimage` is never executed.

```
local pack_cmd = "bash /absoulte/path/script.sh " .. some_other_name .." >> error.log"
os.execute(pack_cmd)
```

Version with handles is not working as well

```
local handle = io.popen(pack_cmd)
local result = handle:read("*a")
handle:close()
```

If I execute `pack_cmd` string manually everything works OK. Executing bash script is also working.

Comment: What does `strace` tell you is happening?

Comment: ...btw, code generation through string concatenation is very bad practice (can lead to injection vulnerabilities). Please consider using an explicit argv array instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for such fast response! I've found out that I don't have permissions to execute this as `www-data` user. Thanks for suggestions as well.

Comment: (by the way, to be a little more concrete about what I meant by "injection vulnerabilities" -- think about what happens if `some_other_name` contains `evil-$(rm -rf ~).iso`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with permissions for `www-data` user.

Comment: Since the solution was specific to your site (such that the question and answer pair isn't likely to help others with the same problem), you might consider deleting the question, unless the answer can be extended to cover diagnosis steps in sufficient detail to be helpful to others.